# Client server architecture for local an network run

Tags: c++, networking, client-server, boost-asio, local

I need advise and may be some thoughts about my issue:

Process1 - the main process which run the server in separate thread and runs the clients.

Process2 - client, who make some work and send result of work to the server.

Communication from client side:

1st send - type of message

2d send - data

3d read - answer from server

Communication from server side:

1st read - type of message

2d read - data

 - process the data

 - send the answer to client

**Some constraints**:
 - This program should be able to run locally and in network.
 - Number of Process2 can be around of 6000
 - C++ language boost::asio library

**Current solution**:
I have the async client. Which do the job and run client for sending the result.
Server is accepting the clients in the loop and when client accepted, server creates the thread and handle the communication.

**Some remark!** For local run, at one time number of Process2 equal to processor cores.

What do you think is this solution good or may be I should use another approach?

Answer (score 0):

You no need create thread for each client in 'Process1', you can use the async function(with prefix 'async_') to avoid block, so all the clients can run in one thread.

refer to:
[https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/chat/posix_chat_client.cpp)